# Overriding Environmental Variables when Calling ECS task using Eventbridge

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I want to use eventbridge to schedule an ECS task at a later time.  My Fargate task uses an environmental variable to pass a s3 filename into the fargate instance using the environmental overrides.  For example when I call the file from a lambda function I use:

```
overrides={
                'containerOverrides': [
                    {
                        'name': 'emailer-ship',
                        'environment': [
                            {
                                'name': 'FILE_PAYLOAD',
                                'value': payload
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ]
            },
```

I'd like to use boto3 to create the new eventbridge rule to run the fargate task, but it seems like overrides are not supported? is that right?  I've found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/pipes-reference/API_EcsEnvironmentVariable.html):
which gives me hope that this may be possible, but I don't see python specific SDK info.

Answer (score 0):

It goes in the `Input` parameter of the [put_targets](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events/client/put_targets.html) function.

```
response = client.put_targets(
    Rule='string',
    EventBusName='string',
    Targets=[
        {
            'Id': 'string',
            'Arn': 'string',
            'RoleArn': 'string',
            'Input': 'string',
```

Given your `overrides` definition in your question, you would set it like this:

```
`Input': json.dumps(overrides)
```