# How to pass containerOverrides to an ECS task when triggering as a target from eventbridge rule?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I want to write a python code that uses boto3 to assign targets to an eventbridge rule. The target should be an ECS task. Also when the eventbridge rule runs/triggers the ecs task it should override the value of an environment variable named `game_id`.

What I have tried is to provide the override information in the `input`

- the function I am using to assign target is `put_targets` on a boto3 (`events`) client
- Inside the array of targets we have to provide in the argument for `Targets` I have an element that defines the ecs_task's trigger config
- Inside this element I have keys like `Id`, `Arn`, `Input`, `RoleArn`, `EcsParameters`
- In the `Input` key I am providing the `json.dumps` of a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
  "containerOverrides": {
    "name": container_name,
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "game_id",
        "value": game_id
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- Inside the `EcsParameters I am providing a dictionary that looks like (some of the values are variables defined in my environment:

```
{
  "TaskDefinitionArn": task_definition_arn,
  "TaskCount": 1,
  "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
  "NetworkConfiguration": {
    "awsvpcConfiguration": {
      "Subnets": ECS_NETWORK_SUBNETS,
      "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED",
      "SecurityGroups": ECS_SECURITY_GROUP
      }
    }
}
```

The put_targets function executes correctly and I am able to see the rule having the correct target, but it is not triggering the ECS task, at first I thought it was a problem with the IAM role that the rule had, but that wasn't the case as when I changed the input from what I had given to an empty dict, it ran with no issues.

In a way you could say I have implemented this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77047939/11327022

What could be the issue?

Specifically how do we provide containerOverrides when setting an ECS task as a target to an eventbridge rule using boto3?[image: ecs task input]

Comment: Is the eventbridge rule actually triggering? Have you checked the cloudtrail logs?

Comment: A missing container override would not prevent the task from being triggered, it would just prevent the task from running properly. If you don't see stopped/failed tasks in ECS, then there is a problem with the EventBridge rule. You need to focus on that before moving on to the container override.

Comment: Your question about specifying container overrides is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046728/overriding-environmental-variables-when-calling-ecs-task-using-eventbridge/77047939#77047939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @paolo points out, let's figured out if the rule is actually triggering. You can see that in the monitoring tab of the rule (if it gets triggered). If it triggers, but you don't see your task being started, it could be an issue when invoking the target. To troubleshoot, add a DLQ to the target configuration (ideally set all retry values to 0 so any error is immediately DLQ-ed) and then inspect the SQS queue for the detail.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this was what I did, the rule was triggering but it couldn't execute the ecs task as I was giving the wrong container_name, reading the logs in the DLQ helped me greatly... I guess my question was somewhat misguided, I just wanted to know a way to debug the flow of execution and thats what DLQ provided